# What will be the order of acidity in the following compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism

[image]
What will be the order of acidity in the following compounds ? From My point of view it should be 3>1>2>4. But the answer given is 3>2>1>4. Can anyone explain how ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are correct. The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of 4-methylphenylacetic acid is quoted as 4.37 [here](https://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB3695209.htm). The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of benzoic acid is quoted as 4.19 by the same source [here](https://www.chemicalbook.com/ProductList_en.aspx?kwd=benzoic%20acid).

Comment: m-nitrobenzoic acid has a pKa of 3.47, so yes the original poster is correct.